# writing a subscriber with 2 arguments

Tags: boost, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, im new to ROS and PCL and i want to process the data provided by a xtion pro live using openni. my goal is to estimate a groundplane using a function

void groundplane (CloudT::ConstPtr cloud_in, CloudT::Ptr cloud_out)
{
...code...
}

So the function needs 2 arguments, a pointcloud cloud_in from the xtion and a pointcloud cloud_out that should be empty at the beginning. searching the web i think i need to use boost::bind, but i cant figure out how. help would be very much appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234094/writing-a-subscriber-with-2-arguments/) by [BBB](https://answers.ros.org/users/25209/bbb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you're trying to use cloud_out as an output parameter. This isn't a good idea.

All of the parameters to your callback function should be inputs. They can be messages or static inputs, but since the arguments (other than the message) are passed in once when you create the publisher, you shouldn't pass in something that the callback will attempt to modify.

Depending on what you're trying to do, you could write your callback to modify a global variable or a class member, or it could publish the output cloud on a new topic.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1